# problems with mice in R: cannot coerce class '"mids"' into a data.frame

Tags: r, r-mice

I have a dataset with about 11,500 rows and 15 factors.  I only need to impute values for 3 of the factors, with only 2 of the factors having any significant number of missing values.  I have been trying to use mice to create imputed datasets, and I am using the following code:

```
dataset<-read.csv("filename.csv",header=TRUE)

model<-success~1+course+medium+ethnicity+gender+age+enrollment+HSGPA+GPA+Pell+ethnicity*medium

library(mice)

vempty<-c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
v12<-c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1)
v13<-c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1)
v14<-c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1)
list<-list(vempty,vempty,vempty,vempty,vempty,vempty,vempty,vempty,vempty,vempty,vempty,v12,v13,v14,vempty)
predmatrix<-do.call(rbind,list)


MIdataset<-mice(dataset,m=2,predictorMatrix=predmatrix)
MIoutput<- pool(glm(model, data=MIdataset, family=binomial))
```

After this code, I get the error message:

Error in as.data.frame.default(data) : 
  cannot coerce class '"mids"' into a data.frame

I'm totally at a loss as to what this means.  I had no trouble doing this same analysis just deleting the missing data and using regular glm.  I'd also like to do a multilvel logistic model on imputed datasets using lmer (that's the next step after I get this to work with glm), so if there is anything I am doing wrong that will also impact that next step, that would be good to know, too.  I've tried to search this error on the internet, and I'm not getting anywhere.  I'm just really learning R, so I'm also not that familiar with the environment yet.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 2):

You need to apply the `with.mids` function. I think the last line in your code should look like this:

> pool(with(MIdataset, glm(formula(model), family = binomial)))

You could also try this:

```
expr <- 'glm(success ~ course, family = binomial)'
pool(with(MIdataset, parse(text = expr)))
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, @Erich.  I actually had this code before, and it also did not work.  It returned the error message:    Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'success' not found    "success" is the correctly written name of the DV, and glm has no problem recognizing it without the imputation steps, so I'm not sure what is going on.  I also found some online tutorials that did this without using the with function, which is why I did the code as listed in the original post, but maybe those tutorials were wrong...

Comment: Sorry for the poor formatting above - but none of the instructions for how to do a line break worked when I posted!

Comment: Did you make sure that model was a formula-object as in my example?

Comment: Yes, it happens both with and without the formula-object part.

Comment: does it also happen when you do not specify the formula in advance, like this? `pool(with(MIdataset, glm(success ~ course, family = binomial)))`

Comment: That seemed to fix the problem @Erich, thanks!  But I don't really understand why?  It's too bad, because for the sake of keeping track of things (and using functions to automate stuff) it would be very, very helpful to be able to specify the model first...

Comment: I added a second solution to my answer. This should enable you to specify the model dynamically.